# Video overlay - how is this effect created?

Tags: after-effects, effects

I came accross this image - and was wondering how to recreate it in after effects?

https://www.truedigital.co.uk/assets/video/us-hero.mp4

Answer (score 2):

I was able to produce it by doing the following:

1. Convert the video to monochrome by turning the saturation down
2. Apply Levels and bring the output black point up to around 30%
3. Put an orange color solid over it and set the opacity to 50%
4. Set the blend mode to "Normal," "Overlay," or "Hard Light"

You can experiment with the black point and blend modes to get the look just right for your footage.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this;
Three built in effects that do it for you, each with differing levels of control...

- CC Toner
- Tritone
- Tint

just colour pick the shades of orange you want.

Answer (score -1):

Just looks like a solid color layer on top with some transparency.

Comment: Yes, that I figured - but what "kind" of overlay is used to produce these kinds of color schemes?

Comment: I just see the hue switched off. Try `Color Correction -> Black & White` effect